# What does "cd && cd -" do on Mac OS terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

Hey fellow computer geeks,

I came across this snippet of code on the Mac OS terminal:

```
cd && cd -
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cd` returns to the home directory

`&&` lets you do something based on whether the previous command completed successfully

`cd -` will switch you to the previous directory

Answer (score 4):

`cd` without arguments changes to your home directory, same as `cd ~`

`&&` lets you chain shell commands together

`cd -` switches back to the directory you were previously in