# Alias/function to open multiple terminal windows AND run commands in each new window

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, terminal, vim

When starting my work day I cd into a project folder. Open three tabs: one for the rails server, one for vim, and one for running git commands and the rails console. I have tried to create an alias, and a couple of functions to do this. However, it runs all the commands in the first window.

How can I pass my focus on to the newly opened tab(s) and execute the second command?

Some of my .bash_profile functions:

```
alias rs=" rails s"
alias gpo="git pull origin"
#nt as in NewTab in current dir
function nt() {
  open . -a "iterm 2"
}
```

What I have tried so far:

```
#go start coding for the day.
alias go='nt | rs; nt | vim; nt | gpo;'

#Go get going.
function Go() {
  nt && rs;
  nt && vim;
  nt && gpo;
}

#GOing to work this time.  Also tried | in place of &&.
function GO() {
  open . -a "iterm 2" && rs
  open . -a "iterm 2" && vim
  open . -a "iterm 2" && gba && gpo
}
```

Minor but important: the command to start rails 'rs' does not fire till I focus back on the first window.

Other questions on similar topics:

1. [Creating a function in .bash_profile](https://superuser.com/questions/351852/chaining-terminal-commands-in-bash-profile)
2. [Using the && command](https://superuser.com/questions/691355/what-does-cd-cd-do-on-mac-os-terminal/691358#691358)
3. [Adding ; to the command](https://superuser.com/questions/285417/on-a-mac-how-can-i-group-together-commands-i-want-run-into-a-alias)